How to use the cols parameter to change the color of certain data points in the albatros function of the metap package?
I would like to create an albatros plot in R Studio, so I downloaded the metap package (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/metap/versions/1.11).
With the help of the description and sample code, I was able to produce a plot with my own data, see below. The studies I want to analyze used different methods, and I would like to display those in different colors. E.g. Method 1 has red Datapoints, Method 2 has blue, Method 3 has green.
I cannot figure out how to make the cols parameter work, every time I input something other than NULL either the code just does not run or I get error messages. Could you guys help me out?
This is the description of the cols parameter:

The pch parameter may either be a single value or a vector of the same
length as p. It may contain anything which is legal as input to the
parameter of the same name in the graphics library and will be used
for the plotted points. The cols parameter works similarly.

Plot:

My code:
albatros(Test_Albatross$p, Test_Albatross$n,
                  contours = list(type = "smd", contvals = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.8), ltys = 1:3),
                  axes = list(ylimit = c(1,100), xlimit = 0.0001,  lefttext = "Negative correlation",
                              righttext = "Positive correlation"),
                  plotpars = list(yscale = NULL, pchs = letters[unclass(Test_Albatross$Kennung)], cols = NULL),
main = "Test2")

My Dataset (Excel):

I already tried:
cols = colors[unclass(Test_Albatross$Method)]
cols = "red"

rgb, hex, values, ...

Try colors()[unclass(d$Method)] instead of colors[unclass(Test_Albatross$Method)]. colors is not a list (which can be [] indexed) but a function producing a list. Thus, you first have to have the function evaluated (by adding () even without arguments inside ()) and then index into the resulting list. Aside: no need to unclass, just do colors()[d$Method]

Looks like a bug in albatros regarding the cols argument.

Hi, thank you for your reply @I_O Sadly, neither colors()[unclass(Test_Albatross$Method)] or cols = colors()[unclass(Test_Albatross$Method)] worked. The code runs, but all the datapoints stay black. Also, it does not recognize it, wehen I put d instead of Test_Albatross, it tells me "object 'd' not found."

According to the help page of albatros
> help(albatros)


plotpars
A list containing

yscale Scaling for y-axis, See details
pchs Symbols to be used
cols Colours for points

... Arguments to be passed through to plot

This says the plotpars argument should contain only 3 plotting parameters (yscale, pch, and col) and any other plotting parameters are to be specified in .... However, cols is not being passed to plot, and this looks like a bug.
albatros(Test_Albatross$p, Test_Albatross$n,
         contours = list(type = "smd", contvals = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.8), ltys = 1:3),
         axes = list(ylimit = c(1,100), xlimit = 0.0001,  lefttext = "Negative correlation",
                     righttext = "Positive correlation"),
         plotpars = list(yscale = NULL, 
                         pchs = letters[Test_Albatross$Kennung], 
                         cols = rainbow(10)))




Interestingly, the following does change the colours of the labels. Unfortunately, the colour of the axes is now linked to the col global argument, and if this is specified, then that will be the colour of the axes. If a vector is specified, then the colour will be the first colour. A trick is to specify the first colour as black. However, the first label ("a") will also have to be black.
albatros(Test_Albatross$p, Test_Albatross$n,
         contours = list(type = "smd", contvals = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.8), ltys = 1:3),
         axes = list(ylimit = c(1,100), xlimit = 0.0001,  lefttext = "Negative correlation",
                     righttext = "Positive correlation"),
         plotpars = list(yscale = NULL, 
                         pchs = letters[Test_Albatross$Kennung]),
         col = c("black", rainbow(9)))




If you don't want the first label to be black, then there is another option. But it is rather tedious. Run the command again with a full rainbow of colours.
albatros(Test_Albatross$p, Test_Albatross$n,
         contours = list(type = "smd", contvals = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.8), ltys = 1:3),
         axes = list(ylimit = c(1,100), xlimit = 0.0001,  lefttext = "Negative correlation",
                     righttext = "Positive correlation"),
         plotpars = list(yscale = NULL, 
                         pchs = letters[Test_Albatross$Kennung]),
         col = rainbow(10))


You get coloured labels, even the first one. But the axes are red (the first colour of the rainbow). We then simply copy the albatros code that constructs the axes and plot these ourselves over the existing plot.
xtrans <- function(p) {
  p2 <- ifelse(p > 0.5, 1 - p, p)
  res <- log(1/p2, base = 10)
  res <- ifelse(p > 0.5, -res, res)
  res
}

sigs <- c(0.050, 0.010, 0.001)
i <- 2
while (sigs[i] > 0.001) {
  sigs[i + 1] <- sigs[i]/10
  i <- i + 1
}

ylabs <- c(1, 2, 5)
maxn <- max(Test_Albatross$n)
i <- 3
while (ylabs[i] < maxn) {
  ylabs[i + 1] <- ylabs[i - 2] * 10
  i <- i + 1
}

axis(1, at = c(-xtrans(sigs), 0, xtrans(sigs)), labels = c(sigs, "null", sigs),
     cex.axis = 0.75, las = 3)
axis(2, at=sqrt(ylabs), labels = ylabs, cex.axis = 0.75, las = 2)




Hi, Thank you so much for the detailed reply! My goal was not to have a different color for every datapoint, but to habe only three different colors, one for each different kind of method that was used. (the last column in the excel sheet named "Method"). I dont mind if the first color is black, I mainly wanted to be able to quickly tell how effective which method was. How can I assign the Method colum to have the colors instead of the Kennung column?

Simply replace col = rainbow(10) with col = Test_Albatross$Method.

I seem to need more reputation to upvote (I am very new here and do not understand everything yet). I marked your answer as the most helpful one. Hope that is useful too

@Edward already pointed out the apparent bug, its location and a solution.
For the fun of tinkering, here's how you can fix the bug (the cols argument does not get passed to the plot instruction) for one session:

copy albatros over to a new function (instead of changing the original in place):

colortros <- albatros


change the operational body of the new function so that plot(...) is replaced with plot(col = cols, ...):

body(colortros) <- 
  albatros |> body() |> deparse1(collapse = "\n") |> 
  gsub(pattern = "plot\\(", replacement = "plot(col = cols, ") |> 
    str2lang()


use the new colorful function (I added the with envelope to avoid spelling out the data source every time):

with(Test_Albatross,
     colortros(p, n,
               contours = list(type = "smd", contvals = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.8), ltys = 1:3),
               axes = list(ylimit = c(1,100), xlimit = 0.0001,  lefttext = "Negative correlation",
                           righttext = "Positive correlation"),
               plotpars = list(yscale = NULL, 
                               pchs = letters[Kennung],
                               cols = Kennung)
     ) 
)

Result (note that I created some dummy data as a screenshot of example data is tedious to reproduce):

